# How to fix this error while clearing subset sums?

Tags: python, math

I'm working on a project which requires me to find sum partitions of a certain value(required_reduction). I have to clear the `total_parts` list from sublists if any which has any value other than 2. index of combs's sublists.

```
Example:
required_reduction = 4 
combs = [[2,1],[3,2]]
total_parts = [[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[2,2],[1,3]]
```

I can't use `[1,3]` because it has "3" in it which is not a value contained in 2.elemnt of "combs" sublists which are 1 and 2. "partition" function was taken from stackoverflow, I'm trying to construct rest.

```
import numpy as np


required_reduction = 16


combs = [[2,4],[3,5],[4,8],[5,13],[8,15],[10,18]]


def partition(number):
    answer = set()
    answer.add((number, ))
    for x in range(1, number):
        for y in partition(number - x):
            answer.add(tuple(sorted((x, ) + y)))
    return answer

total_parts = partition(required_reduction)
total_parts = list(total_parts)



def applicable_partitions(total_partitions, combinations):
    selections = [0]
    for _ in range(0, len(combinations) - 1):
        selections.append(combinations[_][1])
    del selections[0]
    possible_partitions = np.array(np.zeros(1,int))


    for i in range(0, len(total_partitions)-1):
        for j in range(0, len(total_partitions[i]) -1):
            for k in range(0, len(selections)-1):
                if total_partitions[i][j] == selections[k]:
                    continue
                else:
                    total_partitions.remove(total_partitions[i])

    return total_partitions

print(applicable_partitions(total_parts, combs))
```

I am getting this error :

> if total_partitions[i][j] == selections[k]:
>   IndexError: tuple index out of range.

Can someone see why ?

Comment: You are removing elements from `total_partitions` (which changes its length) while iterating it based on its initial length.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much <3